# Merge Query Matching on Dates in Multiple Rows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to merge 2 queries in Power BI Desktop, matching rows based off a user and date column in one query to a row in the other query, where the user matches and the date in the 2nd query is the closest one before the date in the 1st query.

In other scenarios I need to match on more than one column, I'll usually create a composite key to match, but here's it's not a direct match.

Examples of the 2 queries are:

QUERY1

```
User     Activity     Activity Date
User 1   Activity 1   2019-01-24
User 1   Activity 2   2019-03-03
User 1   Activity 3   2019-04-17
```

QUERY2

```
User     Status     Status Change Date
User 1   Status 1   2019-02-05
User 1   Status 2   2019-03-06
User 1   Status 3   2019-04-05
```

And the merged query I'm looking for is:

MERGED QUERY

```
User     Activity     Activity Date   Status
User 1   Activity 1   2019-01-24       
User 1   Activity 2   2019-03-03      Status 1
User 1   Activity 3   2019-04-17      Status 3
```

Both queries are sourced from a REST API. If it was a SQL source, I'd use a SQL query to create a derived island table of start and stop dates based on Query2 and do a BETWEEN join against Query1 and have that be the source for Power BI.

Within the Power Query Editor, how would I get to the merged query result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to do as you suggested and modify the status table to have start and stop dates instead of `Status Change Date`. You can do this by sorting, indexing, and self-merging as I've previously explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313405/fill-time-gaps-with-power-query/54330062#54330062) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814815/add-column-of-previous-values-from-table-of-tables-in-power-bi-power-query/54816156#54816156).

Once you have that, you can load a copy of the status table in each row and use the `User` and `Date` columns to filter the table and finally return a single value for `Status`.

```
let
    Source = <Query1 Source>
    #"Added Custom" =
    Table.AddColumn(Source, "Status",
        (C) => List.First(
                   Table.SelectRows(Status, 
                       each [User] = C[User] and 
                            [Start] < C[Date] and
                            ([Stop] = null or C[Date] <= [Stop])
                   )[Status]
               ),
        type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

This says we take the `Status` table and filter it so that based on the current row the `User` matches and the `Date` is between `Start` and `Stop`. From that filtered table, we select the `Status` column, which is a list data type, so we pick the first element of the list to get the text value of the only member of the list.

Comment: Slightly tweaked the example provided in the 2 links - had to change the index starts so the end date was null for the last range.

[PBIX](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqVXf2M7suvjgY3CMSeV_1riOQ9RcrY) with the full solution