# Merge queries matching on dates and leave null if no match found

Tags: merge, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have got two tables below (examples):

**Table SFID**

| Sales Force ID | Type | Name | Assistant | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | Store A | Ben | 01/04/2020 | 30/04/2020 |
| 123 | ABC | Store A | Jen | 01/05/2020 | 31/05/2020 |
| 123 | ABC | Store A | Ben | 01/06/2020 | 21/06/2020 |
| 126 | DEF | Store B | Tim | 01/04/2020 | 30/04/2020 |
| 126 | DEF | Store B | Tim | 01/04/2020 | null |

and

**Table Activity**

| Transaction ID | Date | Sales Force ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/05/2020 | 123 |
| 2 | 03/06/2020 | 200 |
| 3 | 01/01/2021 | 123 |
| 4 | 02/01/2021 | 126 |

I want my end result to be

| Transaction ID | Date | Sales Force ID | Type | Name | Assistant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/05/2020 | 123 | ABC | Store A | Jen |
| 2 | 03/06/2020 | 200 | null | null | null |
| 3 | 01/01/2021 | 123 | null | null | null |
| 4 | 02/01/2021 | 126 | DEF | Store B | Tim |

To do this, the best solution was the one posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332654/power-query-merge-two-tables-based-on-the-transaction-date-between-two-dates#) with some modifications (allow both To and From to be null). However, **only the row on transaction ID 2 disappears** because that Sales Force had already had assistant entries (they get wiped out on the filtered row step). I also tried the solution presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599361/merge-query-matching-on-dates-in-multiple-rows) but it takes ages to load.

I would like to know if there was a way to guarantee all transactions appear without having to introduce lines to table SFID for periods they don't have assistants and without making the query a really slow one.

This is my code:

```
    let
    Source = Source,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Sales Force ID"},SFID,{"SFID"},"SFID",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded SFID" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "SFID", {"Type", "Name", "Assistant", "From", "To"}, {"Type", "Name", "Assistant", "From", "To"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"SFID",{{"Date", type date}, {"From", type date}, {"To", type date}}),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Date] >= [From] and [Date] <= [To]) or ([Date] >= [From] and [To] = null)or ([From] = null and [To] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(FilteredRows,{"From", "To"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after almost 2 weeks with no response and an unjustified downgrade, I found a solution!

I created a query that would basically produce this table with the above mentioned code.

| Transaction ID | Date | Assistant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | Jen |
| 4 | 02/01/2021 | Tim |

```
let
    Source = Source,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Sales Force ID"},SFID,{"SFID"},"SFID",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded SFID" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "SFID", {"Type", "Name", "Assistant", "From", "To"}, {"Type", "Name", "Assistant", "From", "To"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded SFID",{{"Date", type date}, {"From", type date}, {"To", type date}}),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Date] >= [From] and [Date] <= [To]) or ([Date] >= [From] and [To] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(FilteredRows,{"From", "To"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

And left-joined it on my initial version of **Table Activity**

I kept the information of type Type and Name in a separate Query (as they don't change) and then again left-joined it on the **Table Activity**.

Final query looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Source,
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Sales Force Code"},Info,{"SFID"},"Info",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Info" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Info", {"Type", "Name"}, {"Type", "Name"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Info",{"ID"},IDvsAssistant,{"ID"},"IDvsAssistant",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded IDvsAssistant" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "IDvsAssistant", {"Assistant"}, {"Assistant"})
in
    #"Expanded IDvsAssistant"
```