# Calculated Column Next Date Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the next day in Power BI.

[image: Table Here]

Comment: You should be able to use a double index and self-merge for this similar to my accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313405/fill-time-gaps-with-power-query/54330062#54330062)

Comment: To increase the chance of receiving good quality answers, my suggestion is to stick to the template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Simple but representative example using tables and 4) Expected solution/behaviour based on the example showed in point (3).